# Is there a term for a non-brute-force version of a fuzzer?

Tags: terminology, fuzzing

Thinking of how a fuzzer brute-forces a lot of input to a program to discover vulnerabilities, it seems natural that one would then consider the concept of writing a program that analyzes the target program's structure more fundamentally / intelligently to find similar vulnerabilities more efficiently.

I figure I'm almost certainly not the first one to think of it, so I'm guessing it exists and there's a term for it.

Is there? If so, what, and if not, why?

Comment: Sounds like you are after some combination of fuzzer and taint analysis. Here's one example of a paper (regarding "data flow sensitive fuzzing") that might address some aspects of your question: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec20spring_gan_prepub.pdf

Comment: @hft tyty. Looks like a good read.

Comment: That would be called a better fuzzer.

Comment: @user253751 Well really I was thinking more of boundary calculation. If fuzzing is simulating a bunch of particles thrown at the edges of a polygon to find any holes or concave dips, ____ is running an algorithm on the position and size of the edges to calculate the same results, minus the brute force. Perhaps that's not possible - finding memory boundaries and calculating collisions - but I don't know whether it is or not, so I asked.

Comment: That makes me think of formal verification, which is not a fuzzing tool, but a very tedious and difficult manual process.

Answer (score 1):

The usual term I've heard for such software is a "smart fuzzer", "whitebox fuzzer", or (specifically for fuzzers designed around a particular data format, e.g. XML), "data-aware fuzzer". For example, see [Microsoft's SAGE fuzzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/sage-in-one-slide.pdf) ([more detail on SAGE](https://patricegodefroid.github.io/public_psfiles/cacm2012.pdf)), which was termed a "whitebox fuzzer" and relies on program flow analysis of the binary plus a constraint solver that attempts to mutate the input to hit every code path possible, including things that would be out-of-bounds or similar errors to the original programmer.